# Local Variable to Pointer to Cast

Tags: c, pointers

I have a relatively simple question, which I tried to keep as minimal as possible, but wanted to include an example so people would understand what I am referencing.

I have a function which declares a local variable (`unsigned int`), I then use a pointer to copy the value of that `unsigned int` to a pointer. I know that after that function ends, that local variable will no longer exist. The only thing that really matters to me is the value. I then try to pass it to `func2()` which has to have a `void *` as the argument (wasn't my choice) and just simply look at the value, which I think should be `2` since I added `1`:

```
void func2( void * arg){
    //was not my choice to have void * be the argument.. was a requirment

    unsigned int val = *(unsigned int) arg;
    //When I print this the value should be 2..


}

void createPointer(){
  unsigned int localVariable = 1;
  localVariable = localVariable + 1;
  unsigned int *pointer = &localValue;
  *pointer = localValue;
  //my goal here is to copy the VALUE of the local variable
  //as I need this pointer to still point to this value after this function returns

  //in my actual code, this function is on a whole seperate file.. so it is really important that the pointer is stored in memory

func2( (void *) pointer );


}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   createPointer();
}
```

However, instead when I try to print that variable `val` in `func2()`, it just prints out some random address as text, which makes me assume it is somehow still referencing the `localVariable`, which I only wanted to copy the value of.

So, my question being is there a proper syntax way to copy the value of the local variable? Am I doing something wrong when I cast and uncast to `void *`?

Comment: This code won't compile...

Comment: Please show real complete code. That is, a [mcve]. There are multiple issues with the code as shown and we don't know whether that is really what your code looks like or whether it is just a problem in the way you are describing the issue. So always show a MCVE that exactly reproduces your problem.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes

Comment: If you want the value to persist after a function call finishes, but you want to return a pointer to it rather the value itself (but why?) you would have to allocate space for it on the heap and set the pointer to it before you return it. The calling code would then have the responsibility to free that memory. As an alternative, you could use a `static` variable, but that is much less flexible.

Comment: "I know that after that function ends". Your example does not show that case. You are calling `func2` *inside* the `createPointer` function. So the function `createPointer` has not ended and thus the code shown does not present the issue you are asking about.

Comment: `*(unsigned int) arg;` --> `*(unsigned int *) arg;` . If your compiler didn't give an error message for that line then you would do yourself a big favour by configuring your compiler to operate in standard mode

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be here

```
unsigned int val = *(unsigned int) arg;
```

which is ill formed and I would be very surprised if it compiles at all, but since you say the problem is the printed value is strange, I would assume that it is the reason, the correct way is

```
unsigned int val = *(unsigned int *) arg;
```

which means, cast `arg` to an `unsigned int` pointer and dereference it.

There are a few things to mention about this

1. Whether or not the original value which you passed a pointer to is no longer valid after the caller returns is irrelevant, because if you call this sequentially `func2()` should return before the caller and thus the deallocation would occur after, so the value will be valid for the lifetime of `func2()`.
2. The value inside the function, stored now in `val` lives in the stack frame of `func2()` and is a copy of the original value, but in a different memory location in principle.
3. If this function will execute in a different thread, you can't assume that you copied the value before the function that started the new thread returns, so you would need to store the value in the heap, like this

   ```
   int *pointer;
   pointer = malloc(sizeof pointer);
   if (pointer == NULL) {
       handle_allocation_error();
   } else {
       *pointer = value;
       func2(pointer);
       pointer = NULL; // Prevent having a dangling
                       // pointer
   }
   ```

and at some point in `func2()` you would need to `free()` the pointer.

In principle, this would work given that your sample code is not like your real code. Next time, include the actual code instead and if it's really too much, write a smaller version that would reproduce the problem. Sometimes, while you are writing such smaller version, you find out why the unexpected behavior is happening and you would not need to ask at all.

Also, you don't need `(void *)` in

```
func2((void *) pointer);
```

just

```
func2(pointer);
```

should compile fine.

Comment: You don't need implictly casting from `void*`.

Comment: @͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘ I can't really understand your comment.